# Relative Directories in snakefile using workflow.get_source()

Tags: snakemake

For my workflow, the scripts & snakefile are in a different directory than the output files. I specify the latter using the `workdir` directive, which seems to work fine.

Now in some cases there are static input files in other directories, whose paths I want to specify relative to the snakefile. According to the documentation, I should use `workflow.get_source("path/relative/to/snakefile")`. However this gives me

'Workflow' object has no attribute 'get_source'. Do I need some additional imports?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, it looks like what's used in the code example is `workflow.source_path("path/relative/to/snakefile")` rather than `get_source` - you can give that a try. 
Otherwise, though I don't think it's officially documented, `workflow.basedir` gives you the path of the directory the Snakefile lives in, and you can build the rest of the path off that.

Comment: Many thanks, workflow.basedir is indeed working. For both workflow.source_path and workflow.get_source, the original error remains. Could this be a bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: @KeyboardCat: Your `workflow.basedir` hint saved me a lot of time! Thank you. I started a bounty just to reward you. I'll have to wait a day though to do so.

Comment: @mschilli glad to hear this still helps people!